# When adding a new field, my data type changes from short integer to long integer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-pro

I am having trouble in Pro where, when I'm adding a new field to an attribute table (let's call it "Code"), I m trying to make the data type Short integer. Once i change it to short integer, I run it and a new field is created under Code. When I hover my mouse over it, it says the type is Long integer. I can't seem to fix this no matter what path I take. It's a new field and there is no data I have added to it. I am relatively new to ArcGIS Pro so I'm assuming there's a simple fix to this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take our short [Tour]. Please [Edit] the question to include the width have you specified for the column.  Five or greater and the field will be modified to support all possible values (e.g. 99999 > 2**16-1).

Comment: I have not been advised to add any extra information other than the Name and "Data Type".

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you are using to add this field?

Comment: Add Tracts to ArcGIS Pro session. Add a new field to the Tracts attribute
table. Call it Code.
Make the field type short integer.
Populate the field – Code =10